# Getting generic server error on Image.getBlob() in Appscript

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workspace

In appscript for a Google Slides extension I am getting a generic error in my logs:

`Exception: We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.`

In my code, I am simply getting an Image (PageElement) and trying to:
`image.getBlob()`.  I've also tried to `image.getAs('image/jpeg')` with the same error.  All other functionality around an image object works fine, including getting things other than the image blob.

I can get the ID of the image, and other attributes, I simply cannot return the blob.

This was working as expected about 48 hours ago.

I tried running getBlob() and getAs() on the image with no avail

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information provided, the issue appears to be on Google's server side which could be affected by an outage or maintenance. You may check your Google Apps Script Dashboard for details since you mentioned that it was working before. Try doing basic troubleshooting like clearing cache and cookies as this might help. If all else fails, try contacting Google Workspace Support for further assistance.[1]

[1] https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en

Comment: Thank you, I 100% believe it is related to a Google Workspace update/release that is killing this functionality.  I have been trying to report it but it seems like without a paid support package, I cannot?